# External domain to CNAME in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, subdomain, cname

I have a ASP.NET website that generates subdomains on-the-fly. So users can generate urls like user1.domain.com, user2.domain.com and so on.

When I am trying to CNAME another domain user1.com to user1.domain.com, the root document i.e. domain.com is visible instead of user1.domain.com.

Can you help me out?

Edit: I have dynamic subdomains which are actually a rewrite rule like domain.com?profile=user1

Comment: I have solved the problem. My subdomains were actually "rewrites" that could be generated on the fly from database. Have written logic in page_load event to handle the same.

Answer (score 3):

u need to create A record instead of cname,

look i have domain http://remindu.technothumb.com/

i have create one subdomain http://testdns.technothumb.com

and add name in iis .

both website work fine! check this image

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. My subdomains were actually "rewrites" that could be generated on the fly from database. Have written logic in page_load event to handle the same.